# C++ function-object template argument deduction style

Tags: c++, functional-programming

I'm trying to distill my ad-hoc programming into modular and re-usable components by adopting a more functional programming style, but that makes me write everything twice.

As an example, I have a state `stateT state` that is updated by a configurable function-object `step`.

```
template<typename sT, typename T1, typename T2>
struct Step {
  T1 func1;
  T2 func2;

  Step(T1 f1, T2 f2) : func1(f1), func2(f2) {}

  sT operator()(sT state) {
    state.A = func1(state.A);
    ... using func2() and internals of state ...
  }
};
```

So that I would not have to type

```
auto step = Step<stateT,typename_of_func1,typename_of_func2>{func1, func2};
```

I have made a `make_stepper`

```
template<typename sT, typename T1, typename T2>
auto make_stepper(sT state, T1 func1, T2 func2) {
  return Step<sT,T1,T2>(func1, func2);
}
```

Now I can write

```
stateT state{...constructor arguments...};
auto step = make_stepper(state, func1, func2);
state = state(step);
```

To provide a nice interface I end up writing a `make_X` function for every templated function-object `X`. Is this good style or am I just fooling myself? Can I avoid writing the `make_X` functions? Or should I change the whole approach?

Comment: After the reinterpretation of `auto`, things have actually become much nicer than they used to be.

Comment: Note that you should use **perfect forwarding** in `make_stepper` to limit the count of copies made.

Comment: @MFH: I disagree, see my previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21230320/what-is-the-correct-argument-type-for-a-function-object).

Comment: @Mankka: So instead of perfect forwarding you use explicit copies to increase the count of potential unnecessary/temporary copies made, sounds reasonable…

Comment: @MFH: To clarify, my question is not the main point, but Steve Jessop's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21231081/1693829) "...callable objects are taken by value."

Comment: @Mankka: It's your choice after all, but if you ask if it's good style to use `make_`-functions that, the answer still would be: yes, if they use perfect forwarding (that's how the standard defines `make_shared` and `make_unique` for example). This solution is even mentioned in the question you're referring to by Kerrek SB. You seem to mistake algorithms - which yes take their functor by value - with factory methods (which generally don't do that e.g. `make_shared`). It's actually really simple: want to pass the parameters to another function (e.g. constructor)? => use perfect forwarding!

Comment: @MFH: +1 Fair enough, function-objects store by value, factory methods forward perfectly. The only thing I loose is the readability of the library internals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way it is normally done, also in C++ Standard Library. So you are on the right track and there is no way to avoid writing make_ functions, since there is no way the deduction can work as requested directly for classes/structs.